# problem with sklearn MultiLabelBinarizer()

Tags: scikit-learn, multilabel-classification

starting from my dataframe x_train, I would like to onehot the column 'genres'. There are more then 1000 unique different genres, but when I use the function multilabelbinarizer it reports only 31 columns, and looking at the class they don't really make sense, looking on the help page it suggest not to use list but an array, as I did here in the example, but still is not giving me a 36158 x 1388 matrix. What I'm missing?

```
x_train:

   movie_id year                   synopsis                            genres
0   30924   2005    Cruel But Necessary is the story of Betty Muns...   Drama
1   34841   2012    Yorkshire, 1974, the Maynard family moves into...   Drama Horror Thriller
2   23408   2017    When a renowned architecture scholar falls sud...   Drama
3   39470   1996    The story dealt with Lord Rama and his retalia...   Children Drama
4   7108    2003    A Thai playboy cons a girl into bed and then l...   Comedy Drama Horror Thriller
... ... ... ... ...

x_train.shape:
(36518,5)

gen = np.array(x_train['genres'])
np.unique(gen).shape
(1388,)


from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
multilabel_binarizer = MultiLabelBinarizer()
y=multilabel_binarizer.fit_transform(gen)

y.shape:
(36518, 31)

multilabel_binarizer.classes_:
array([' ', '-', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'H', 'I', 'M', 'N', 'R', 'S', 'T',
      'W', 'X', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'h', 'i', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'r',
      's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'y'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: If anyone want to try it out, here is the link, it is an open notebook on Kaggle: 
    https://www.kaggle.com/domizianostingi/very-easy-nlp/edit/run/43087491

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The weird output is due to the fact that the parameter of `fit_transform()` must be an iterable of iterables ([see doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html#sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.fit_transform)).

The format of your variable `gen` must be changed, in order to have the genres separated. Divide the strings containing the genres to a list of strings, in order to separate the genres, like:

```
'Drama Horror Thriller' => ['Drama', 'Horror', 'Thriller']
```

You can do it in one line:

```
gen = [x.split(' ') for x in list(x_train['genres'])]
gen

[['Drama'],
 ['Drama', 'Horror', 'Thriller'],
 ['Drama'],
 ['Children', 'Drama'],
 ['Comedy', 'Drama', 'Horror', 'Thriller']]
```

`gen` has now the correct format for `fit_transform()`:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

multilabel_binarizer = MultiLabelBinarizer()
y = multilabel_binarizer.fit_transform(gen)

multilabel_binarizer.classes_
['Children' 'Comedy' 'Drama' 'Horror' 'Thriller']

y
array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Comment: I try the to put the function you suggested, but now it returns a vector of 1 with length 1388: array([[1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1]]) . Shouldn't it be a matrix of dimension 36158 (number of observations) x 1388 ( number of unique genres) ?

Comment: Ok my bad, I did not apply it to your problem exactly. I edited the answer

Comment: Not really, It now return me a matrix with 36158 x 38, I'm trying to figuring out why, I think this is due to the fact that in this way it recognize only the first term present

Comment: I think you must have only 38 different genres. For you, ''Drama Horror Thriller'' is 1 or 3 genres ?

Comment: I would like to consider "drama horror thrilelr" as a single value, since my aim is to implement a multiclass model (instead of a multilabel as it could be if 'drama horror thriller' are 3 different classes)

Comment: Ok, for this use case replace `x.split(' ')` by `[x]` when creating `gen` in my answer, in order to not split the genres. As it is not a multilabel problem, another encoder such as `pandas.get_dummies(x_train['genres'])` may be more suitable.